# MongoDB distinct on array of embedded document doesn't use index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

let's say I have a collection of documents like this, where there is the stock field with an array of embedded documents:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  item: "abc",
  stock: [
      { size: "S", color: "red", quantity: 25 },
      { size: "S", color: "blue", quantity: 10 },
      { size: "M", color: "blue", quantity: 50 }
  ]
}
```

I have created a multikey index like this:

```
db.items.createIndex("stock.size")
```

but when I run:

```
db.runCommand({distinct: "items", key: "stock.size"})
```

it returns:

```
{
    "values" : [
        "S", "M"
    ],
    "stats" : {
        "n" : 1730969,
        "nscanned" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1730969,
        "timems" : 13716,
        "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

It performed whole collection scan and didn't use index. Can I somehow speedup distinct query on array of subdocuments?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and just posting to let you know that since 3.2 you can use explain to have more details on the execution :

```
db.items.explain().distinct('stock.size');
```

I tested my index and it is actually working when filtering, but not when using distinct(). Hopefully it will soon :/